# String transformation using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, transformation

I'm learning Spark, and trying to write quite simple app. 
As input I have log string, which looks like

```
INFO - {timestamp} - {path} - {json message}
INFO - 124534234534534 - test.class - {"message": "something happened"]
```

I want to pass it to ElasticSearch. So I need to take {timestamp} and put it to new field to {json message}, so it should look like

```
{"timestamp": "1234343132", "message": "something happened"}
```

Can someone help me with this transformation using Java?

Comment: Can you include your own attempts to solve this?

Comment: I easily do it in pure java, without spark. Tried to find some examples with transformation (not word count) - all of them on scala. If I missed something - please point me to some article or similar sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create  a [`Function`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function.html)`<String, String>` which takes a line of log and returns JSON string.

   ```
   Function<String, String> f = new Function<String, String>() {
     public String call(String s) { return ...; }
   }
   ```
2. Read data using `SparkContext.textFile`

   ```
   JavaSparkContext sc = ...;
   JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile(...)
   ```
3. `map` created RDD using function defined in point 1.

   ```
   rdd.map(f);
   ```